# Change the VideoTrack of a MediaStream object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

In a Nutshell: **I'm trying to change the `VideoTrack` of a `MediaStream` object.**

(Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/MediaStream_API)

I have a MediaStream object `__o_jsep_stream_audiovideo` which is created by [the sipml library](https://code.google.com/p/sipml5/).

`__o_jsep_stream_audiovideo` looks like this:

[image: stream object]

So it has *one* AudioTrack and *one* VideoTrack. At first the VideoTrack comes from the users camera (e.g `label: "FaceTime Camera"`).

According to [the Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebRTC/MediaStream_API#Remove()):

> A MediaStream consists of zero or more MediaStreamTrack objects, representing various audio or video tracks.

So we should be fine adding more Tracks to this Stream.

**I'm trying to switch/exchange the VideoTrack with that from another stream.** The other stream (`streamB`) originates from Chromes ScreenCapture api (`label: "Screen"`)

[image: streamB]

I tried:

`__o_jsep_stream_audiovideo.addTrack(streamB.getVideoTracks()[0])`

which doesn't seem to have any effect.

I also tried assigning the videoTracks directly (which was desperate I know).

I must be missing something obvious could you point me in the right direction?

I'm running

- Chrome (Version 34.0.1847.131) and
- Canary (Version 36.0.1976.2 canary)
- OSX 10.9.2

Comment: are you handling the `onaddtrack` event in the mediastream object?

Comment: @bwtrent that could the problem I'm not handling it. How should I go about that?

Comment: actually, this [looks like a bug](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=871)

Comment: You may have to re-negotiate the stream so that the remote side gets the new track. But, the simplest solution would be to simply add the stream to the peer connection and not modify the tracks...

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that issue. It seems like the local media stream modifications (adding/removing tracks) are ignored (for now). I guess I'll try to add the second stream (as you suggested). I'll let you know. thanks again @bwtrent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding and removing tracks on a MediaStream object [do not signal a renegotiation](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=1565) and there are also issues with a MediaStream having two tracks of the [same type in chrome](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=871&q=track&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Status%20Owner%20Summary).

You should probably just add the separate mediastream to the peer connection so that it can fire a re-negotiation and handle the streams. The Track add/remove functionality in chrome is very naive and not very granular and you should move away from it as much as you can.

Comment: Thanks again. Although I was able to exchange the videoTracks of the MediaStream, it doesn't trigger a renegotiation. So you answered my original question.

Comment: as of today, adding or removing tracks on a mediastream triggers renegotiation

Answer (score 2):

When you talk about change video track, we mean 2 areas:

1. **change the remote video track** (what the others can see from u)

WebRTC gets new version of doing that, since it deprecates addStream/removeStream.
However, the excelence is that they introduce new interface replaceTrack

```
stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
    // remote
    qcClient.calls.values().forEach(function(call) {
    var sender = call.pc.getSenders().find(function(s) {
        return s.track.kind == track.kind;
    });
    sender.replaceTrack(track);
    });
});
```

2. **change your display video** (You see yourself)

Better to just add a new video element (or using existing video element) But assign srcObject to the new captured stream