# WebRTC RTCmulticonnecttion swap camera without refresh

Tags: webrtc, rtcmulticonnection

I am using RTCmulticonnection.

[RTCMultiConnection](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/RTCMultiConnection/)

I want to swap camera without refresh the page. Is any solution to swap camera on run time?

Comment: Please check this demo: https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com/demos/Switch-Cameras.html To test it: Setup WebRTC connection among two tabs or computers, change camera from any tab and it will work. Currently it allows you change camera 2-3 times only i.e. you can switch between cameras only 2-3 times.

Comment: check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39385615/how-to-swap-camera-sources-in-webrtc-while-in-a-call-javascript-apis